# dockPanelSuit not showing positions to dock a form

Tags: c#, dockpanel-suite

I am writing a simple windows application which contains the main form and other 4 forms.
All 4 forms are docked to the main form using dockPanelSuit, that works fine with functionalities like docking, undocking to the main form.

the same application .exe when I run on a remote machine, I am not able to see the dockable positions when I click and hold on a form.

The code for docking a form is as follows.

orderupdatesform = new OrderUpdatesForm();
orderupdatesform.Show(dockPanel1, DockState.DockBottom);

I am not able to find the problem.

Comment: If you mean you cannot see dock indicator when using Remote Desktop Connection, you should check if you are using the latest Windows and RDP client.

Comment: @LexLi But i created simple application with docking, and run on the remote machine is working fine. is there any possibility that, threads affect the visibility of dock indicator?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem with the docking on other machines.
The problem was with .NET framework. We should have the .NET framework that supports the docking functionality for Operating system.